# freeRADIUS: Error when changing inner auth

Tags: configuration, authentication, wpa2-eap, freeradius

I'm using the Version 2 of freeRADIUS. I've successfully changed the default eap type.

Now I'm trying to change the inner auth because I need pap as default.

I've tried to change the inner auth for ttls but then this happens:

```
   ttls {
    default_eap_type = "pap"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    include_length = yes
   }
rlm_eap_ttls: Unknown EAP type pap
rlm_eap: Failed to initialize type ttls
/usr/local/etc/raddb/eap.conf[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[310]: Failed to load module "eap".
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[252]: Errors parsing authenticate section.
```

I've tried to change the inner auth for peap as well, but same problem as before:

```
   peap {
    default_eap_type = "pap"
    copy_request_to_tunnel = no
    use_tunneled_reply = no
    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes
    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    soh = no
   }
rlm_eap_peap: Unknown EAP type pap
rlm_eap: Failed to initialize type peap
/usr/local/etc/raddb/eap.conf[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[310]: Failed to load module "eap".
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[252]: Errors parsing authenticate section.
```

Why it doesn't recognize pap? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that PAP isn't an EAP type.  PAP is an authentication type.

EAP-TTLS is the only widely used EAP type which can use a PAP inner, so I'm assuming you're using that.

When the server processes EAP-TTLS, it extracts the attributes inside EAP-TTLS' TLS tunnel and creates RADIUS attributes from them.  It then 'proxies' a request containing these attributes (possibly merged with those from the RADIUS packet carrying EAP), and sends them to another virtual server (the default being 'inner-tunnel').

In order to perform PAP authentication in the inner tunnel, you need to set up PAP as you would for RADIUS.

*etc/raddb/sites-available/inner-tunnel*

```
server inner-tunnel {
    authorize {
        ldap | sql | files | whichever module you use to retrieve passwords

        pap
    }

    authenticate {
        pap
    }
}
```

Note: You also need to select PAP as the inner method on the supplicant. There's no way to negotiate whether the supplicant uses an inner EAP method, or does PAP/CHAP/MSCHAPv2 using tunnel attributes. The supplicant sends attributes, the server goes along with whatever it sends. If the supplicant sends an EAP-Message attribute and the EAP module is configured, the server will do EAP. If the supplicant sends a User-Password attribute and the PAP module is configured the server will do PAP.

This is distinct from EAP, where the supplicant and server can negotiate the EAP method. There's a bunch of example exchanges in [RFC5281](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5281#section-15.1) where you can see the different attributes being sent.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Edited answer to include some more detail.